# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xef' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, xml-parsing

I want to parse my XML document. So I have stored my XML document as below

```
class XMLdocs(db.Expando):  
   id = db.IntegerProperty()    
   name=db.StringProperty()  
   content=db.BlobProperty()
```

Now my below is my code

```
parser = make_parser()     
curHandler = BasketBallHandler()  
parser.setContentHandler(curHandler)  
for q in XMLdocs.all():  
        parser.parse(StringIO.StringIO(q.content))
```

I am getting below error

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xef' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 517, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)   
  File "/base/data/home/apps/parsepython/1.348669006354245654/mapreduce/base_handler.py", line 59, in post
    self.handle()   
  File "/base/data/home/apps/parsepython/1.348669006354245654/mapreduce/handlers.py", line 168, in handle
    scan_aborted = not self.process_entity(entity, ctx)   
  File "/base/data/home/apps/parsepython/1.348669006354245654/mapreduce/handlers.py", line 233, in process_entity
    handler(entity)   
  File "/base/data/home/apps/parsepython/1.348669006354245654/parseXML.py", line 71, in process
    parser.parse(StringIO.StringIO(q.content))   
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)   
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)  
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)   
  File "/base/data/home/apps/parsepython/1.348669006354245654/parseXML.py", line 136, in characters   
    print ch   
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xef' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Your stacktrace shows that your executing code is different to what you pasted - and that you're using `print`. Don't use print in a WSGI app!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It seems you are hitting a UTF-8 byte order mark (BOM). Try using this unicode string with BOM extracted out:

```
import codecs

content = unicode(q.content.strip(codecs.BOM_UTF8), 'utf-8')
parser.parse(StringIO.StringIO(content))
```

I used `strip` instead of `lstrip` because in your case you had multiple occurences of BOM, possibly due to concatenated file contents.

Comment: I have done exactly as mentioned in answer but getting the above error, First it was giving me at position 0 mentioned in question and now it is giving me at position 5785 mentioned in prev comment

Comment: I recommend converting any string `s` which produces the error with `s = unicode(s.strip(codecs.BOM_UTF8), 'utf-8')`. `s` refers to the name of your strings.

Comment: Try to replace `lstrip` with `strip`.

Comment: I understand what you are suggesting and I had done the same error in detail : ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xef' in position 5785: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: It's an encode error during the conversion of an unicode to string during printing. It won't contain a UTF-8 BOM, it can't be decoded back to unicode, and the error is because it countains non-ASCII characters - removing them would *break* the content, and the BOM is only one of them.

Answer (score 112):

The actual best answer for this problem depends on your environment, specifically what encoding your terminal expects.

The quickest one-line solution is to encode everything you print to ASCII, which your terminal is almost certain to accept, while discarding characters that you cannot print:

```
print ch #fails
print ch.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

The better solution is to change your terminal's encoding to utf-8, and encode everything as utf-8 before printing. You should get in the habit of thinking about your unicode encoding EVERY time you print or read a string.

Comment: in my case , i was printing twitter stream to a terminal , and it was working fine. Then i wanted to redirect the programs output to a file , i started getting 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 32-36 . Later , as in this answer, i used print tweet.encode("utf-8",ignore) , and it all worked.

Answer (score 56):

Just putting `.encode('utf-8')` at the end of object will do the job in recent versions of Python.

Comment: What do you mean with "recent versions of Python"? Only `3.x`, or also `2.7`?

Comment: Python 2.7 is clearly recent since it's still in wide spread use.

Comment: Works for me on Python 2.7

Answer (score 30):

This worked for me:

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
content = smart_str(content)
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem according to your traceback is the `print` statement on line 136 of `parseXML.py`. Unfortunately you didn't see fit to post that part of your code, but I'm going to guess it is just there for debugging. If you change it to:

```
print repr(ch)
```

then you should at least see what you are trying to print.

Comment: -1 for non-unicode solution to an obvious unicode encoding problem.

Comment: The unicode encoding problem is with the print statement. Yes, there may be other issues but fixing the print to not crash is the immediate issue.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you're trying to print an unicode character to a possibly non-unicode terminal. You need to encode it with the `'replace` option before printing it, e.g. `print ch.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, 'replace')`.

Comment: printing is not essential, the main statement for me where I am getting error is of parse statement

Comment: @Mahesh: It's YOUR code that's causing the problem, at line 136 of parseXML.py -- either fix it yourself, or show us that part of the code so we can help you.

Answer (score -1):

An easy solution to overcome this problem is to set your default encoding to utf8. Follow is an example

```
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Comment: Do not do this. [why it breaks code](https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/)

Comment: Can you explain the reason?

Comment: There is a link in my comment that explains it.  Essentially libraries expect the default of `ascii` to remain the default.  It is why `setdefaultencoding` is not normally available without the `reload` trick.