# Python - Replace non-ascii character in string (»)

Tags: python, regex, string, encoding, decoding

I need to replace in a string the character "»" with a whitespace, but I still get an error. This is the code I use:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# other code

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
mystring = soup.find('a').text.replace(' »','')
```

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbb' in
>   position 13: ordinal not in range(128)

But If I test it with this other script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
a = "hi »"
b = a.replace('»','')
```

It works. Why this?

Comment: googling the error you get as it is, i get this back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141559/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xef-in-position-0 There should be something there you can use

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In order to replace the content of string using `str.replace()` method; you need to firstly decode the string, then replace the text and encode it back to the original text:

```
>>> a = "hi »"
>>> a.decode('utf-8').replace("»".decode('utf-8'), "").encode('utf-8')
'hi '
```

You may also use the following regex to remove all the non-ascii characters from the string:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r'', 'hi »')
'hi '
```

Comment: The regex version is the fastest. Instead of using `[^\x00-\x7f]` I used `[^\x20-\x7E]` to also remove the ASCII control characters from 0 up to 31 and 127.

Answer (score 9):

@Moinuddin Quadri's answer fits your use-case better, but in general, an easy way to remove non-ASCII characters from a given string is by doing the following:

```
# the characters '¡' and '¢' are non-ASCII
string = "hello, my name is ¢arl... ¡Hola!"

all_ascii = ''.join(char for char in string if ord(char) < 128)
```

This results in:

```
>>> print(all_ascii)
"hello, my name is arl... Hola!"
```

You could also do this:

```
''.join(filter(lambda c: ord(c) < 128, string))
```

But that's about 30% slower than the `char for char ...` approach.