# How can I create a string in english letters from another language word?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, translation

I need to find a way to rewrite words(translit) from some languages into English language. For example `привет` (in Russian) sounds like `privet` (in English).

Meaning and grammar don't matter, but I'd like it to have a more similar sounding. Everything should be in Python, I have diligently looked up on the internet and haven't found a good approach.

For example, something similar to this:

```
translit("юу со беутифул", "ru") = juu so beutiful

translit("кар", "ru") = kar
```

Comment: There is no easy solution to this problem, but you could create a mapping file for letters so that п maps to P. You will have to manually create the files though.

Comment: So you are looking for a cyrillic to roman/latin converter and not a language converter? Have you searched "cyrillic to roman converter library" or "python cyrillic to roman converter"?

Comment: i saw a couple approaches for couple languages. But i don't need in super solution, something simple will be good. I think, there is a big package for these things.

Comment: I understand from your example that translit doesn't do what you want, have you tried creating a custom language pack?

Comment: not only cyrillic, but approach for other languages too. There is constant stream of words and i should convert them in english.

Comment: it is good converting above for me, but only russian isn't sufficient.

Comment: Without using a specially built dictionary, that seems to be an impossible endeavor. In many languages, the same letters sound differently depending on the words they are used in. Heck, in some languages there are even words that have the exact same spelling yet different pronunciation (eg: French “le *président*” => the President / “ils *président* la réunion” => they chair the meeting ; first sounds like in English, second sounds like "presid").

Comment: thanks all 
i haven't thought about that. It seemed that i don't need in very accurate solution. If some words lost correct pronunciation don't matter. You know, when you lost you keyboard and write on another language characters.

Comment: @spectras: Are you sure about "ils *président*"? My French is really rusty, but I think  both are pronounced something like "presiDOH" (with a nasalized final vowel, obviously).

Comment: @Schmuddi> absolutely certain. First example has the final nasal. In the second example however, it's the plural form of verb “présider”. Such plural forms are silent, unless the next word start with a vowel (in which case the liaison can be pronounced as just “t”). — full disclosure: I am from Paris ;)

Comment: @spectras: Fair enough, I stand corrected. It's things like these why French and I never got along so well. This, and stuff like the subjonctif. :)

Comment: "ils président" ->ils president ( it doesn't matter 
as you spell over syllables

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you should give [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/) a try:

```
>>> import unidecode
>>> unidecode.unidecode("юу со беутифул")
'iuu so beutiful'
>>> unidecode.unidecode("die größten Probleme")
'die grossten Probleme'
>>> unidecode.unidecode("Avec Éloïse, ils président à l'assemblée")
"Avec Eloise, ils president a l'assemblee"
```

Install it with `pip`:

```
pip3 install unidecode
```

Comment: Definitely better than transliterate, it cannot do reverse but decode all characters. wp

Comment: Definitely a great library made with nice hand-crafted tables!

Comment: Being hand-crafted is great, but it's also the reason why it's one-way – you only get ASCII output, nothing else. A modified version of @alvas' approach works well if you want to remove diacritics ("accents"), but stay within a script, eg. "ὰ"→"α".

Comment: just want to add that for german, this is not quite good, 'größten' should be 'groessten'

Comment: @dre_84w934 Indeed, `unidecode` doesn't have language-specific rules (that would require it to do language idenfification first).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are already using it; but you can use [`transliterate`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/transliterate/1.9) package.

Basic install with pip:

```
pip install transliterate
```

Then the code

```
# coding: utf-8

from transliterate import translit

print translit(u"юу со беутифул", 'ru', reversed=True) # juu so beutiful
```

**WITH CUSTOM CLASS**

As @Schmuddi propose, you can create your own custom class to handle german special characters, (works only with python 3.X though).

```
pip3 install transliterate
```

Then the code:

```
# coding: utf-8

from transliterate import translit
from transliterate.base import TranslitLanguagePack, registry

class GermanLanguagePack(TranslitLanguagePack):
    language_code = "de"
    language_name = "Deutsch"

    pre_processor_mapping = {
        u"ß": u"ss",
    }

    mapping = (
        u"ÄÖÜäöü",
        u"AOUaou",
    )

registry.register(GermanLanguagePack)

print(translit(u"Die größten Katzenrassen der Welt", "de")) 
#Die grossten Katzenrassen der Welt
```

Bonus, the French one:

```
class FrenchLanguagePack(TranslitLanguagePack):
    language_code = "fr"
    language_name = "French"

    pre_processor_mapping = {
        u"œ": u"oe",
        u"Œ": u"oe",
        u"æ": u"ae",
        u"Æ": "AE"
    }


    mapping = (
        u"àâçéèêëïîôùûüÿÀÂÇÉÈÊËÏÎÔÙÛÜŸ",
        u"aaceeeeiiouuuyAACEEEEIIOUUUY"
    )


registry.register(FrenchLanguagePack)

print(translit(u"Avec Éloïse, ils président à l'assemblée", 'fr'))
#Avec Eloise, ils president a l'assemblee
```

**OTHER POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

Since transliterate doesn't cover the german langage (yet?), you can use another package to directly translate sentences: [`py-translate`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-translate) but it uses google translate so you do need an internet connexion.

Basic install with pip:

```
pip install py-translate
```

Then your code:

```
# coding: utf-8

from translate import translator

print translator('ru', 'en', u"юу со беутифул")
print translator('de', 'en', u"Die größten Katzenrassen der Welt")
```

Comment: thanks 
but i've already used it. It is not sufficient. There are words on german.

Comment: Armenian
Bulgarian (beta)
Georgian
Greek
Macedonian (alpha)
Mongolian (alpha)
Russian
Ukrainian (beta)
 only supported

Comment: There is also the package using google traduction, but you need an internet connexion and it's not really relevant. Sorry That I misunderstood your quesiton.

Comment: @Alex: Have you noticed that you can register your own transliteration mapping for ``transliterate``? Writing a mapping for German to something resembling English seems to be a fairly easy task. I don't think that you'll find any closer match for your problem.

Comment: thanks for your efforts, but i don't need an online tool(:

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution to @lenz. But I do like @lenz's suggestion of `unidecode` better =)

From 
[Python - Replace non-ascii character in string (»)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40872126/python-replace-non-ascii-character-in-string) and [Can somone explain how unicodedata.normalize(form, unistr) work with examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682397/can-somone-explain-how-unicodedata-normalizeform-unistr-work-with-examples)

To resolve umlauts and accent and graves:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r'', normalize('NFD', u"Avec Éloïse, ils président à l'assemblée"))
u"Avec Eloise, ils president a l'assemblee"
```

But it doesn't solve sharp-S character and Cyrillic though:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r'', normalize('NFD', u"die größten Probleme"))
u'die groten Probleme'

>>> re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r'', normalize('NFD', u"юу со беутифул"))
u'  '
```

Comment: "ß" (LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S) is not the same thing as "β" (GREEK SMALL LETTER BETA)!

Comment: The NFD approach is pretty sweet, but it's a pity there are no decomposed versions of characters like "ø", "œ" etc. So  for a good coverage, there's no way around hand-crafted tables.

Comment: Thanks! hahaha, sharp S it is. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is another possible solution using regex, you can configure this function to replace the special characters for the characters you want:

```
import re

def remove_accents(string):
    if type(string) is not unicode:
        string = unicode(string, encoding='utf-8')

    string = re.sub(u"[àáâãäå]", 'a', string)
    string = re.sub(u"[èéêë]", 'e', string)
    string = re.sub(u"[ìíîï]", 'i', string)
    string = re.sub(u"[òóôõö]", 'o', string)
    string = re.sub(u"[ùúûü]", 'u', string)
    string = re.sub(u"[ýÿ]", 'y', string)

    return string
```